# Running scripts after object creation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scripting, model

I'd like to run a script that does some evaluation of user-entered data after it is successfully created. I have a model representing the data, but how do I specify that the model class should execute function X after an instance is successfully created?

Part 2: would it be more appropriate to put the code I want to execute in with the model or with the helper?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want an `after_create` callback in the model.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M001375